# Issues with if-statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a list like this:

```
<f:option1>0</f:option1>
<f:option2>50 000</f:option2>
<f:option3>100 000</f:option3>
<f:option4>150 000</f:option4>
<f:option5>200 000</f:option5>
<f:option6>250 000</f:option6>

<f:max_value>150 000</f:max_value>
<f:min_value>0</f:min_value>

<f:value1>1,50</f:value1>
<f:value2>2,00</f:value2>
<f:value3>3,00</f:value3>
<f:value4>4,00</f:value4>
<f:value5>5,00</f:value5>
<f:value6>6,00</f:value6>
```

This list changes all the time, and I want to write an if-statement to get the correct value

```
$target_option = 50 000;//Should get me $target_value = 2,00

if (($option6 > 0) && ($option6 <= $target_value) && ($min_value <= $target_value) && ($max_value => $target_value)){
    $target_value = $value6;
}elseif (($option5 > 0) && ($option5 <= $target_value) && ($min_value <= $target_value) && ($max_value => $target_value)){
    $target_value = $value5;
}elseif (($option4 > 0) && ($option4 <= $target_value) && ($min_value <= $target_value) && ($max_value => $target_value)){
    $target_value = $value4;
}elseif (($option3 > 0) && ($option3 <= $target_value) && ($min_value <= $target_value) && ($max_value => $target_value)){
    $target_value = $value3;
}elseif (($option2 > 0) && ($option2 <= $target_value) && ($min_value <= $target_value) && ($max_value => $target_value)){
    $target_value = $value2;
}elseif (($option1 > 0) && ($option1 <= $target_value) && ($min_value <= $target_value) && ($max_value => $target_value)){
    $target_value = $value1;
}
```

Anyone see what Im doing wrong, or if there is an better way of doing this?

## Edit:

Se my complete code here: http://pastebin.com/5pfh4JzF

## Edit 2

Found the error on another statement.

Comment: How are you reading in this data?

Comment: There is not an error, but nothing gets returned. When I try my list of 2000 entries, not a single one is returned with this if-statement.

Comment: check my answer. use any Code editor to avoid this kind of errors ! :)

Comment: Added pastebin for the whole code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 errors

1

```
$target_option = 50 000;
```

shoud be

```
$target_option = 50000; // no spaces
```

2

the last statement of each of them

```
($max_value => $target_value)
```

should be

```
($max_value >= $target_value)
```

use any Code editors to avoid this kind of errors

http://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: Changed as you suggested, but still no luck.